# In Leaflet, how to know when map.fitBounds actually changed anything?

Tags: leaflet

I have a click event on a map feature that zooms into that feature when clicked by the user

Map starts like this:
[image: normal zoom]

When a user clicks on the map feature:
[image: after clicking on the map feature]

```js
L.geoJson(geoJsonFeatureCollection, {
  style,
  onEachFeature
}).addTo(map)

function zoomToFeature (e) {
  map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds())
}

function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    click: zoomToFeature
  })
}
```

On a second click on the same map feature, after being already zoomed in, I'd like to forward the URL to another page (the info HTML page of that feature). But I can't distinguish both situations.

How can I know in `map.fitBounds` if the map bounds were already fitted, i.e., if the method actually did/zoomed/panned anything?

Comment: I think this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I think you want to go to a different URL if the last two user actions were click on the same polygon. Set a flat on clicking a polygon, unset it on a `move` or `zoom` event, check that flag when clicking on a polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same calculation function from leaflet and check if it equals to the current map state:

```
function zoomToFeature (e) {
  const bounds = e.target.getBounds();
  const target = map._getBoundsCenterZoom(bounds);
  if(target.zoom === map.getZoom() && map.getCenter().equals(target.center)){
    // bounds already fitting
  } else {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}
```

Maybe you need to change the margin of `equals`. Default: `.equals(target.center, 1.0E-9)`